# Firebase Database Rules Permission Denied when children set to true

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to setup some firebase rules on specific children objects, but I keep getting
`Listener at /Jobs failed: permission_denied`

I'm using these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Jobs": {            
        "$job": {
          ".read":true,
          ".write":true
        }
      }
}
```

However, when I remove the path segment to the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Jobs": {
      ".read":true,
      ".write":true
}
```

it works.

Am I missing something with the paths? [I have been following this as a guide.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the rules and how do you want to query your data?

Comment: I'm trying to only show certain "Jobs" to specific users. I want to query on all "/Jobs" from the app. I think I understand now why it's happening, but I'm not sure if there's a workaround or if it's not intended for this. I think why it's happening is because querying "/Jobs" defaults to false in the first set of rules, and the "/Jobs/$job" isn't what I'm querying. @Callam

Comment: Is there a way to use a wildcard in the data variable? So like ".read":"data.child('wild_card').child('status').val() == 'test'" ?

Comment: How do you decide which jobs you show to which users?

Comment: From what you've shown, you're falling into the "rules are not filters" trap. I recommend studying that [section of the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), and some of the [questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

Comment: Yup, that seems to be the case @FrankvanPuffelen. I think I have a better understanding of it now, thanks for the input.

Comment: @JacobVanAssche Good to hear! For future questions, be sure to also include the code that is having problems. Right now I could luckily gather it from the error message, but that isn't always the case.